# Long Query String in Ajax Call (querystring limit has been exceeded)

Tags: jquery, ajax, iis-7, query-string

I am using following ajax call in my .net application. this function execute on click of a button.

```
$.get("PublishIntermediate.ashx",
        { 
          SiteID: "" + SiteID + "",
          PageID: "" + PageIDs + "",
          UserID: "" + UserID + "",
          Location: "" + "website" + ""  
        },
        function(data) 
            {
    //other code    
            }
        );
      return false;
```

It works fine when PageIDs variable is not too long. But sometimes "PageIDs" variable becomes too long(if user has too many pages) and the ajax call's length, which I checked from firebug , is too long and the server is returning error. I checked from IIS7 that `querystring limit has been exceeded`. Is there any other way for performing this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GET method has a limit for data

> Although the specification of the HTTP protocol does not specify any maximum length, practical limits are imposed by web browser and server software.
>   http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html

, use POST method in jquery, use $.post(paras) instead $.get(paras).